# How to insert infinity in Impala Table

Tags: hive, impala

How to insert Infinity and NaN in Impala. Same test works well with Hive but throwing error in Impala.

```
> create table z2 (x double);
> insert into z2 values (1),("NaN"),("Infinity"),("-Infinity");
Query: insert into z1 values (1),("NaN"),("Infinity"),("-Infinity")
ERROR: AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'TINYINT' and 'STRING' of 
exprs '1' and ''NaN''.
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this for Impala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Impala Mathematical Functions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_math_functions.html), you're missing the `CAST(x AS DOUBLE)`.

> Infinity and NaN can be specified in text data files as inf and nan respectively, and Impala interprets them as these special values. They can also be produced by certain arithmetic expressions; for example, 1/0 returns Infinity and pow(-1, 0.5) returns NaN. Or you can cast the literal values, such as CAST('nan' AS DOUBLE) or CAST('inf' AS DOUBLE).

So your insert should read:

```
> insert into z2 values (1), (CAST ('nan' AS DOUBLE)), 
  (CAST ('inf' AS DOUBLE)), (- CAST ('inf' AS DOUBLE));
```

Then you'll see:

```
> select * from z2;
+-----------+
| x         |
+-----------+
| 1         |
| NaN       |
| Infinity  |
| -Infinity |
+-----------+
Fetched 4 row(s) in 0.12s
```